# How to give different row id's for two different variables in the same table, one for folders and the other for medias?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, model-view-controller

I need some help plz!!
I need to give each variable an id to use it later to make an ajax click on method action to enter the $folder subdirectory's inside the table.
Do I have to do that in the controller or in the ajax?
The data tables plugin is used in the application: https://datatables.net/

// These are the three functions: Controller function, Ajax function, and Bootstrap, as you can see the folders at the top of the table then the medias will be listed, I am not having any problem with the code and its working fine.

```
public function ajaxSearchMedias() {
        $this->checkAccessPlaylists(false) ;

        $this->loadModelSpe('Media');
        $this->loadModelSpe('media');

        $orderby = 'name' ;
        $orderway = 'ASC' ;
        $search = NULL ;

        if(isset($_POST['order'][0]["column"])) {
            $column_to_order = (int) $_POST['order'][0]["column"] ;
            if($column_to_order == 2)
                $orderby = 'length' ;   
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'][0]["dir"])) {
            $way_to_order = $_POST['order'][0]["dir"] ;
            if(strtolower($way_to_order) == 'desc')
                $orderway = 'DESC' ;    
        }

        if($_POST['search']["value"]) 
            $search = $_POST['search']["value"] ;

        $data = array();

        // Display folders in the content playlists

        if(isset($_POST['folderId']) && $_POST['folderId'] != -1) {
                $level = $this->media->getFolderLevel($_POST['folderId'])->level;
                $level++;
                $parentFolder = $_POST['folderId'];
                $folders = $this->media->getFoldersByParentFolderId($_POST['folderId']);
                $medias = $this->media->getMediasByParentFolderId($_POST['folderId']);
        }else {
                $siteId = $_SESSION["sess_id_site"];
                $folders = $this->media->getRootFoldersBySiteId($siteId);
                $medias = $this->media->getRootMediasBySiteId($siteId);
        }
        if($folders) {
            foreach ($folders as $folder){
                //$name = $newtext = wordwrap( $one_media->name, 15, "\n", true );
                $name = $folder->name;
                $name = '<span>'.$name.'</span>';

                $unformatted_length = Helper::getLengthForMedia(array("type" => $folder->type)) ;

                $length = Helper::convertSecondsToMinutesSeconds($unformatted_length) ;

                $orientation_and_type_icon = '<div class="" data-name="'.htmlspecialchars($folder->name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'" data-length="'.$length.'"  data-unformatted_length="'.$unformatted_length.'" data-id="'.$one_media->id.'"  data-type="media"  >' ;
                $orientation_and_type_icon .= '<span class="icon">'.Helper::getIconForTypeAndOrientationForMedia($folder).'</span>' ;
                $orientation_and_type_icon .= '<span class="thumbnail" style="display:none;">'.Helper::getThumbnailForMedia($folder, $this->current_id_company, $this->current_id_site, "img-thumbnail").'</span>' ;
                $orientation_and_type_icon .= '<button type="button" id="'.$folder->name.'" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></span></button>' ;
                $orientation_and_type_icon .= '</div>' ;

                array_push($data, array('orientation_and_type_icon' => $orientation_and_type_icon, 'name' => $name, 'length' => $length));
            }
        }

        // Display Medias in the content playlist

        $medias = $this->Media->getMediasForContentPlaylists($search, $orderby, $orderway, 500, $this->current_id_site, $id_folder = NULL);

        if($medias) {
            foreach ($medias as $one_media){
                //$name = $newtext = wordwrap( $one_media->name, 15, "\n", true );
                $name = $newtext = $one_media->name;
                $name = '<span>'.$name.'</span>';

                $unformatted_length = Helper::getLengthForMedia(array("type" => $one_media->type, "length" => $one_media->length)) ;

                $length = Helper::convertSecondsToMinutesSeconds($unformatted_length) ;

                $orientation_and_type_icon = '<div class="pl_media_data" data-name="'.htmlspecialchars($one_media->name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'" data-length="'.$length.'"  data-unformatted_length="'.$unformatted_length.'" data-id="'.$one_media->id.'"  data-type="media"  >' ;
                $orientation_and_type_icon .= '<span class="icon">'.Helper::getIconForTypeAndOrientationForMedia($one_media).'</span>' ;
                $orientation_and_type_icon .= '<span class="thumbnail" style="display:none;">'.Helper::getThumbnailForMedia($one_media, $this->current_id_company, $this->current_id_site, "img-thumbnail").'</span>' ;
                $orientation_and_type_icon .= '</div>' ;

                array_push($data, array('orientation_and_type_icon' => $orientation_and_type_icon, 'name' => $name, 'length' => $length));
            }
        }

       $json_result = json_encode(array("data" => $data));

        print $json_result; 
    }

// This is the ajax function, this function list media's and folders using data tables plugin without any problem, the main problem is giving an id to folders different than the media's so I can use it to make the click on for the folders.

    this.getMediaList = function() {
        var jqxhr = $.getJSON( url + 'plugins/DataTables-1.10.12/media/js/i18n/fr_FR.json', function( data ) {});
        jqxhr.done(function(data) {
            self.pl_dt_language_json = data ;
            var languages_dt =  self.pl_dt_language_json ;
            languages_dt = $.extend(languages_dt, {"sSearch": ""});

            self.pl_medias_dt = $('#pl_medias').DataTable({
                language: languages_dt,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "type" }, 
                    { "data": "orientation_and_type_icon" },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "length" },
                ], 
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "searchable": false, "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }, 
                    { className: "pl_media_cell_type", "targets": [ 0 ] } ;
                    { className: "pl_media_cell_icon", "targets": [ 1 ] } , 
                    { className: "pl_media_cell_name", "targets": [ 2 ] } , 
                    { className: "pl_media_cell_length", "targets": [ 3 ] } 
                ], 
                "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]], 
                initComplete: function(settings, json) {
                    // search
                    if($('#pl_medias_filter input').eq(0).size() > 0) {
                        $('#pl_medias_filter input').eq(0).attr("placeholder", "Rechercher un fichier") ;
                        $('#pl_medias_filter input').unbind();
                        $('#pl_medias_filter input').on( 'keyup', function () {
                            var searchInput = $(this).val();
                            if(searchInput.length == 0) {
                                window.clearTimeout(self.pl_medias_dt_filter_status);
                                self.pl_medias_dt.search( searchInput ).draw();
                            } else {    
                                if(searchInput.length < 3) {
                                    window.clearTimeout(self.pl_medias_dt_filter_status);
                                    self.pl_medias_dt_filter_status = setTimeout(function() {
                                        self.pl_medias_dt.search( searchInput ).draw() ;
                                    }, 3000);
                                } else {
                                    window.clearTimeout(self.pl_medias_dt_filter_status);
                                    self.pl_medias_dt_filter_status = setTimeout(function() {
                                        self.pl_medias_dt.search( searchInput ).draw()  
                                    }, 1000);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 
                drawCallback: function(settings) {
                    // refresh drag and drop
                    self.initDragDropSortElementForContentPlaylist();   
                },
                "serverSide": true,
                "paging":   false,
                "lengthChange" : false,
                "scrollY": 122, 
                "info": false, 
                "ajax": {
                    url : url + "playlists/ajaxSearchMedias", // json datasource
                    type: "post"
                }, 
                "dom": '<lf<t>ip>'
            }); 
        }); 
    },

// This is the Bootstrap script

        <div class="pl_block_wrapper pl_block_media_wrapper row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 pl_block_label"><span>AUTOPROMO</span></div>
            <div class="col-xs-10 pl_block_container_middle">
                <table id="pl_medias" class="table table-striped table-bordered"  width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Nom</th>
                            <th>Durée</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see the three Bootstrap ajax jquery and PHP scripts.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to translate the paragraph between the code blocks.

Comment: Hello, Haem this is the translation : 
Content playlists are playlists built from movie-related media (posters and trailers) and image and video content that you have loaded into the Autopromo part, thank you for you're comment, do you have any solution ? :-)

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't my area of expertise. You should [edit] your question, and while you're at it, try to shorten your code examples into a [mcve].

Comment: what are you trying to achieve on click? Your question is very unclear

Comment: Hello again Mr. Haem, what you asked is done :-)

Comment: Rachel Gallen, thank you for your comment :-) also the question is edited and minimized and it is more clear I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to add an id and a class :-) :

$('#pl_medias tr').attr('id', 'table-row-id');

$('#pl_medias tr').attr('class', 'table-row-class');

Thank you very much!